# How do I get a unicode symbol/emoji to appear in a listbox in C#?

Tags: c#, unicode, listbox, symbols

The user can "lock" an item on the listbox to prevent it from being altered. I'm trying to get the symbol '' (unicode 1F512) to appear next to the item, but I keep getting a square '◻'. 
It appears in Microsoft Visual Studio in the editor, where the font is Consolas. I changed the font to Consolas in the listbox, and also tried a number of other fonts, but none of them worked.

Comment: How do you encode the lock character?

Comment: @michauzo I have it append to the end of the string. When the item is locked, `label += "";`, and when it is unlocked, `label = label.Replace("", "");`.

Comment: Try using "\uD83D\uDD12" instead of ""

Comment: It works, I use Win10 and listBox is showing ""

Comment: @michauzo It's still showing the square for me. I think the problem is that I'm accessing Visual Studio remotely via Citrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work out of the box with the default font `Microsoft Sans Serif`.

The following code works for me. It's not production quality, just for proving the point.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add("");
}

private void buttonUnlock_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Items[0] = listBox1.Items[0].ToString().Replace("", "");
}

private void buttonAppend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Items[0] += "";
}
```

At first I thought it could be a problem with your language/font settings but if Visual Studio editor is able to show the unicode characters correctly, it doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: I believe the problem could be that I'm accessing Visual Studio remotely through my school via Citrix, who is on Windows 7 while I'm on Windows 10. If everyone is saying it should work fine, that's the only other reason I can come up with.

Comment: That setup can certainly bring some unknowns to the equation! You could also search for `Windows 7 Unicode characters not showing` or something. There are some language and font settings you could check out just to be sure everything's fine on the system.